# sshing using gcloud leads to agent refusal

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am trying to ssh in to a google compute engine using gcloud and this used to work fine. But for some reason I have been hitting a wall for a while now. It works fine from the console. The instance is box-standard default instance.

I keep getting

```
google compute ssh test

sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
Permission denied (publickey).
```

and more verbosely

```
google compute ssh test -vvv

...
bug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/mike/.ssh/google_compute_engine
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fpSHA256:bW6Bpi2N67+MIGbRkfLRcdl5ghxQWOAtiRiYazy1JXU
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:bW6Bpi2N67+MIGbRkfLRcdl5ghxQWOAtiRiYazy1JXU
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
```

I have tried with a fresh project, but the same result. Re-installed google cloud sdk, same result. I must be missing some setting value, but I have no idea what I am missing. I have ssh keys (the standard ones created by gcloud, called google_compute_engine(.pub) in my .ssh directory.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Cheers, Mike

Comment: Can you add some more detail on the VM you're attempting to SSH into? How was it created? From what image?

Comment: it is a standard debian instance (updated in the question). I am actually trying this as I had trouble using it with dynamically created instances with ansible [compute-video-demo-ansible].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying loads of things, I found that

```
sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-keyring
ssh-add -D
```

- a reboot resolved this.

Comment: I did this and Linux now only goes into tty on boot. Problem still not resolved